# Understanding NOAA/GFS0P25 dataset of Google Earth Engine scale change

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation

I have noticed that there are a big differences between the forecasting values of the years 2018-2019 against 2020 for  'total_precipitation_surface'.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-03', '2019-01-04')) // mean 4~ 8 kg/m^2

                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-03', '2020-01-04')) // mean 0.0004 kg/m^2!!!

var Pre_TPS= dataset.select('total_precipitation_surface');
```

Are there some factor that we need apply?

Comment: Very strange. I'd add a link to a working script and post it to the developer forum, if you haven't already.

Comment: I have found the exact same error.. Have you found the reason?

Comment: Their database seems to have changed again on July/23/2020. I am applying the factor .divide(10) now.. instead of multiply(10000), which used to be the case.